# Error: Could not find the correct Provider<LanguageChangeProvider> above this Languages Widget

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to translate my app that has different screens to different languages using localizations and .arb files. The following code it shows how I implemented in MaterialApp and I only included the provider and localization in the main file, not all the pages:

The following are the package versions:

```
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  localization: ^2.1.0
  provider: ^5.0.0
```

Here is the LanguageChangeProvider class:

```
class LanguageChangeProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  Locale _currentLocal = new Locale("en");

  Locale get currentLocal => _currentLocal;

  void changeLocalLanguage(String _localLanguage) {
    this._currentLocal = new Locale(_localLanguage);
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider<LanguageChangeProvider>(
          create: (context) => LanguageChangeProvider(),
        ),
        StreamProvider<Userid>.value(
          value: AuthService()
              .user, //the user is from services auth and non function stream
          initialData: null,
        ),
      ],
      child: Builder(builder: (context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          locale: Provider.of<LanguageChangeProvider>(context, listen: true)
              .currentLocal,
          localizationsDelegates: [
            S.delegate,
            GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
            GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
            GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
          ],
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          color: Color(0xFF13294b),
          title: 'Personal Expenses',
          theme: ThemeData(
            colorScheme: ColorScheme.light(
              primary: const Color(0xFF13294b),
            ),
            buttonTheme: ButtonThemeData(textTheme: ButtonTextTheme.primary),
            accentColor: Colors.amber,
            fontFamily: 'Quicksand',
            textTheme: ThemeData.light().textTheme.copyWith(
                  headline6: TextStyle(
                    fontFamily: 'FjallaOne',
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize: 18,
                    color: Color(0xFF13294b),
                  ),
                  button: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                ),
            appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
              textTheme: ThemeData.light().textTheme.copyWith(
                    headline6: TextStyle(
                      fontFamily: 'FjallaOne',
                      fontSize: 20,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      backgroundColor: Color(0xFF13294b),
                    ),
                  ),
            ),
          ),
          home: Wrapper(),
        );
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to replicate your issue by removing the **Builder** widget that you're assigning as the child of the **MultiProvider**:

[image]

Then I added it again and I'm able to pull values from the **LanguageChangeNotifier** service down the widget hierarchy. For example, I added a property called "valueFromLanguages" in the **LanguageChangeNotifier**:

```
class LanguageChangeProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  
  String valueFromLanguages = "Hello from the Languages Provided Service!";
  Locale currentLocal = Locale.fromSubtags();
}
```

then I pulled it using the **Provider.of** inside the **Wrapper** widget and I was able to see the value, as in:

```
class Wrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  
  @override 
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Text(Provider.of<LanguageChangeProvider>(context).valueFromLanguages)
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here's a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/romanejaquez/51d10cfb779d7f3d7d4a06632dc81b0e) I created real quick (I mocked a few things to make it work) but pretty much illustrates my point that the way you originally have it, it should work. Just make sure you're accessing the provided service down in the hierarchy the correct way.

Comment: I tried to implement it but still same error, the language is not even changing. Also, it is showing me that the getter of specific variable was called on null as shown below: The getter 'Enteryourpassword' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: Enteryourpassword

Comment: And did you run the Gist I provided? Is your structure in a similar fashion? I'd like to see how you're accessing the provider down the hierarchy. The issue you're reporting now I don't think has to do with the Provider. Can you confirm?

Comment: Yes, I accessed the provider as a following: "S.of(context).Signin", but it seems that the program is calling my variables on null

Comment: what's that "Signin"? is that a method / property somewhere? In the AuthService maybe?

Comment: The "Signin" is a variable where I am assigning a value to it for a translation in. arb file as shown below: "Signin": "Signin",
 "Expensesmanagement": "Expenses Management",

Comment: I see - so your issue is how the .arb files are being loaded. You're trying to access the .arb files inside the LanguageChangeProvider. You're gonna have to inject those values above the LanguageChangeProvider service so its context can have access to the inherited context via which it can pull down the injected .arb files.